# How to convert YOLOv4 feature vectors to bounding boxes?

Tags: c++, detection, tensorrt, yolov4

I implement object detection code for Yolov4 using tensorrt c++ pipeline. Although tensorrt c++ api is not user friendly at all, I managed to preprocess image and inference the model. I, however, have 3 outputs which are in shape of 18x52x52, 18x26x26 and 18x13x13. How can I convert these outputs to bounding boxes?

For example my outputs for a person picture go like this:
`0.103638 -0.646484 -0.632324 -0.922852 -0.981445 -0.602539 ...` which has a size of 18x52x52 = 48672

Answer (score 0):

I found the way so I'm going to post here if anyone wonders someday.

You need to create a yolo layer plugin and use this plugin as a last layer to YOLO network. I can't find my plugin because it must be stored in private. This plugin should be a .so file and you need to link this library against your library. In your library you need to include plugin's header file and your network is ready to go.